# filepicker.io storeUrl responds with error code 153 in IE, executes onError callback twice

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm having trouble with filepicker.storeUrl in IE9. It's running the onError callback with an FPError having a code of 153, which doesn't appear to be documented anywhere - and the filepicker debug script

```
<script src="https://api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker_debug.js"></script>
```

doesn't help, it just gives me the following:

```
{"code":153,"message":"Unknown error when storing",
 "moreInfo":"https://developers.filepicker.io/answers/jsErrors/153"}
```

(Here's that unhelpful link: https://developers.filepicker.io/answers/jsErrors/153)

Here is an example of my parameters to storeUrl:

```
filepicker.storeUrl("http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2012-12-02/4614a5a79/03e18973a79745449ae6ff8b9a44af6a.png",{"location":"S3","filename":"03e18973a79745449ae6ff8b9a44af6a.png"}, onSuccess, onError);
```

Additionally, the onError callback gets fired twice for just one call to storeUrl. :(

Unfortunately, it seems to work fine in Firefox. And filepicker.pick() is fine in IE as well, just storeUrl seems to be giving me problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short story: bad behavior on our end, fix going out tomorrow. Should work on https.

Long story:
Turns out because XDomainRequest forces protocol matching, if your website was http we hit our endpoint at http://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3.

On the server side, we enforced https, serving up a redirect to the HTTPS version. This caused a double error to be fired, once for the redirect 301 being a bad response and once for the 405 for an invalid GET call to the url.

While we'd love to ensure that all api calls are done over https, in this case XDomainRequest forces us to use http, so we will now allow http calls to the store endpoint.